# Array indexes to number and number reversed

Tags: code-golf, string, number, array

Given an input array having minimum length `2` and maximum length `9` having any initial values output an array having length `2` consisting of the 1-based indexes of the array represented as either an integer or string in forward and reverse order.

The values of the array or string do not matter and are ignored. For example:

```
[undefined,null] -> [12,21]
```

**Test cases**

Input -> Output

```
["a","e","i","o","u"] -> [12345,54321] // valid
[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}] -> [123,321] // valid
[-1,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99] -> ["123456789","987654321"] // valid
[0,1] -> [01,10] // invalid, not a 1-based index, `01` is not a valid integer
[1999,2000] -> [12,"21"] invalid, output either integers or strings
```

**Winning criteria**

Least bytes.

Comment: Isn't this just, "Count up to the array length, then back down?"

Comment: Can we output an array containing 2 arrays?

Comment: @Quintec Not ideally. That is an unnecessary complication. Though if that is the only way to achieve the approach that you are considering, then do so and provide a note to that caveat of the approach at the answer.

Comment: @guest271314 Well remember, this is code golf. If I can output a 2d array if saves me a few bytes.

Comment: Although the question is boring and trivial, it should not be closed just because of that...

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
n=len(input())+1
b=10**n/81-n/9
print[b,10**n/90*n-b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfnJ@SqmCroK6u/j/PNic1TyMzr6C0RENTU9uQK8nW0EBLK0/fwlA3T9@Sq6AoM68kOkkHImhpoJWnmxT7H6iTK7UiNVkBbJKWguX/aEMdw1guEImgkVmobHQeJh@bCFAMAA)

For example, for \$n=5\$:
\begin{align}
12345 &= 11111 + 1111 + 111 + 11 + 1
\\ &= (11111.\bar1 + 1111.\bar1 + \dots + 1.\bar1) - (0.\bar1 \times 5)
\\ &= \frac{10}{9} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 10^{k} \right) - \frac n9 
\\ &= \frac{10}{9} \left( \frac{1-10^n}{1-10} \right) - \frac{n}{9} 
\\ &= \frac{10^{n+1}-1}{81}-\frac{n+1}{9}
\end{align}

We use integer (floor) division, so the surplus \$\frac{1}{81}\$ gets rounded away.

For the descending part, if `b=12345` we compute something like `66666-12345 == 54321`.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of the approach?

Comment: `b=10**n/81-n/9` saves 2

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 44 bytes

```python
s='123456789'[:len(input())]
print s,s[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcvLCsMgEEDRdfyK2Y1CCtG@B/IlIQvb2kRIJqIG2q@3z/U9NzzzuLAp9yXC5HjII3iGaHlw0tSgG0Wi8hzWDC1Mdr7cLP3zjytRuYe7AiKW1KI2293@cDydsaM3kN9VKtWLED1nSHXqiDa6L5/hBQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>55</s> 52 bytes

```python
a=''
for i in input():a+=`-~len(a)`
print[a,a[::-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxbCoMwEEX/XUXIT7QdIYn1kYArkYCpTWmgJCIKLWK3nk4Lc@bCPczM7/URg0xTvDnSE8ZYsj1j2T0uxBMfcOZtzQttz/1Yfp4u5LYYs3nxYR0s2EHrUhiT8DBzLzeR/6MTqdNALQXqEI9EZKMmG3astThgp1eq5S8nqqsDTSlASqgquFygrqFpoG2h60AplBwEbqGUAsk5N18)

Explanation:

```python
# initial value: empty string
a=''
# iterate over input
# will work with any iterable object: list, tuple, dict, set, string, etc.
for i in input():
# add to a string representation of its length+1
    a+=`-~len(a)`
# print list, composed from a and its reversed version
print[a,a[::-1]]
```

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```python
lambda i:`map(abs,range(-len(i),-~len(i)))`[1::3].split('0')[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BCsIwFAX3PUXIxgR@JUlraz54A28QA021aqBNQ60LEb16TXExzINZvPia72NQy/FwWno3tBdHPDaDi8y1D5hcuHUs77vAPIf8@x@cN0YiFnb7iL2f2UZsuEHMpV2u40R8iAliDHUUaJfwiTHxpBZIZt4poPzAm7YU1eozxeJjITO5BKWgKKAsYbeDqoK6hv0etF6rALlKaq1BCSGsxYzEyYeZHFm65csP)

Explanation:

```python
lambda i:`map(abs,range(-len(i),-~len(i)))`[1::3].split('0')[::-1]

# unnamed lambda
# example input: ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't']

# create range from minus length of input to length+1
# ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't'] -> [-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
                  range(-len(i),-~len(i))
# change every value in range to its absolute value
# [-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5] -> [5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
          map(abs,range(-len(i),-~len(i)))
# get string representaion of list
# [5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5] -> '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]'
         `map(abs,range(-len(i),-~len(i)))`
# get each third element from string, starting from index 1, returns string
# '[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]' -> '54321012345'
         `map(abs,range(-len(i),-~len(i)))`[1::3]
# split string over '0', returns list of 2 values
# '54321012345' -> ['54321','12345']
         `map(abs,range(-len(i),-~len(i)))`[1::3].split('0')
# reverse list
# ['54321','12345'] -> ['12345','54321']
         `map(abs,range(-len(i),-~len(i)))`[1::3].split('0')[::-1]
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of the approach?

Comment: @guest271314 Done

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
J,JṚ$Ḍ
```

### Explanation

```
J      # Converts an array to [1, ...len(arr)]
 ,     # Paired with
  JṚ$  # The same array as before, reversed.
     Ḍ # Convert the digits to integers.
```

I'm no Jelly master, so likely sub-optimal.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Lx@vhzlkqD3f0/P//P9pQR8FCR8FER8FYR8FIR8EyFgA)

Comment: Alternative equal answer: `Jm0ŒHḌ`

Comment: Hint: can you remove the duplication in the code?

Comment: Dunno why it works, but [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99L5@HOWSoPd/T8//8/2lBHwUJHwURHwVhHwUhHwTIWAA "Jelly – Try It Online").

Comment: @totallyhalloween because `$` combines the two links to it's left into a monadic function, so it's a bit like `let f(x)=[x,reverse(x)];v=J(leftArgument);v=f(v);v=fromDecimal(v)`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
āÂ‚J
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SOPhpkcNs7z@/49WSlTSUUoF4kwgzgfiUqVYAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/I42Hmx41zPL6r/M/OlopUUlHKRWIM4E4H4hLlWJ1FCDihrE60UpJSjpGIDpZScc4FiSla6hjZKRjbKxjYqJjaqpjZqZjbq5jYaFjaRkbCwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ā       # List in the range [1, length of (implicit) input-list]
        #  i.e. ["a","e","i","o","u"] → [1,2,3,4,5]
 Â      # Bifurcated (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy)
  ‚     # Pair both list into a single list of lists
        #  i.e. [1,2,3,4,5] and [5,4,3,2,1] → [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1]]
   J    # Join the individual items of the inner lists together (and output implicitly)
        #  i.e. [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,4,3,2,1]] → ["12345","54321"]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>64</s> 60 bytes

```python
a=''.join(map(str,range(1,-~len(input()))))
print[a,a[::-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxNCsIwFIT3PUXIJlFeJUl/E@hJQhexBo1oWmoLSqlXr68OfDMwAzN8plsf1db1F08awhjbXMPY6d6HyJ9u4K9phNHFq@cS0u/DRx7iME/8sCsZxhAn68BZY1LZthseJP7tO/I/PJJis9RRoB4JSI/MtE3sgrWRKyz0TI3as6MmW3FJJSgFWQZ5DkUBZQlVBXUNWuMoQKJLrTUoIUT7Aw)

-1 with thanks to @KevinCruijssen

-3 with thanks to @DeadPossum

Comment: You can remove the space at `print[a]` to save a byte.

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYxNCsIwFIT3PUXIJlFeJUl/E@hJQhexBo1oWmoLSqlXr68OfDMwAzN8plsf1db1F08awhjbXMPY6d6HyJ9u4K9phNHFq@cS0u/DRx7iME/8sCsZxhAn68BZY1LZthseJP7tO/I/PJJis9RRoB4JSI/MtE3sgrWRKyz0TI3as6MmW3FJJSgFWQZ5DkUBZQlVBXUNWuMoQKJLrTUoIUT7Aw)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - I shouldn't have missed that one :-/

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
S¤,d↔ŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/jQEp2UR21Tjjb8B4JoXUMdIyMdY2MdExMdU1MdMzMdc3MdCwsdS8tYAA)

### Explanation

```
S¤,d↔ŀ  -- input xs (list)
     ŀ  -- indices [1..length xs]
S   ↔   -- do the following with itself and itself reversed:
 ¤,d    -- | undigits and join as tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 76 bytes

```java
a->{String[]r={"",""};int i=1;for(var x:a){r[1]=i+r[1];r[0]+=i++;}return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU@xboMwEN3zFSdLSFAS1Ky4ROrSreqQbojBAROZgo3OR9QI@dupgZClw@l07929964RN3Foqp9Jdb1BgsbPyUCqTV747h9WD7okZfRMlq2wFj6F0jDuAPrh0qoSLAny7WZUBZ3nwjOh0te8AIFXGy2rAB8PnbevSyNLyov9tnaCOpvE4TRuAGYjY3vGHFeaQGVHXhsMbwLhNxXRiPmxyFQ8N475axH7IeYOJQ2oAbmb@OK4GfkgJC1ZyB5RAEYmvIH0pXwZXwNzC@fW29lwu1@u01Ujekqc75Zkl5iBkt7HpjpkgU0hsIFme3hHFHebVFL232b9K5wFoidFG1wnou/b@0pH0eo/h3E7N/0B)

Comment: Tried to find something shorter, but to no avail.. Got [84 bytes by using substrings](https://tinyurl.com/y84p7ewy) and [89 by using integer division and modulo](https://tinyurl.com/y9kmoqac).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Hmmm, I tried other versions as well before posting this one, but all used explicit loops. So your ideas were quite different from mine and that's nice :)

Comment: That's why I commented it. :) Normally I wouldn't really bother. I also tried oeis.org formulas like `floor(10/81 * 10^n - n/9)` or `(10^n * (9*n-1)+1)/81`, but as expected it's way too long due to all the casts and `Math.pow`: [104 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/yc2p55aw).

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 6 bytes

```
£╒y_xα
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q4kdTJ1XGV5zb@P9/tFKiko5SKhBnAnE@EJcqxQIA)

```
£╒y_xα
£       Length of input array
 ╒      Range from 1 to n
  y     Join
   _x   Duplicate and reverse
     α  Wrap top two elements in array
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 43 bytes

Returns an array of 2 strings.

```javascript
a=>a.map(_=>(a+=++i,b=i+b),i=a=b='')&&[a,b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcpNCoMwEIbhfY@RRVUyivE/wngRkTKxWlKskdp2I549TbfFxcvAfM@dPrT2T728wtlcBzuiJWwoetDiX7DxiSPnGhRqrgLQSKjQ84LzuSVQne3NvJppiCZz80e/ZcSADS7tMq4364Lg9Kc2x2qxw8YUq5Pf7Vmd7gcyFJAkkKaQZZDnUBRQllBVIOUBjkEcfIWUEpI4jt1mvw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to [ovs](/u/64121).*

```hs
((,)=<<reverse).(`take`"123456789").length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzLCoMwFET3/YohdKFwlcR3QL@kFQw2PjA@UNvPb6rbOouzGM5Mp7ZBG2Ob4mkdh9wiz1f90eumXd@pdjXoiokgjOIkzSRzfaOndu/sqPoJBV7zDUeWtZ923NHgwRQjMH2iPzGfeLPy3/MEIQgIYUiIIkIcE5KEkKaELCNIeZlwgriUQkp5PHHOS/utG6PazXr1svwA)

Comment: ``((,)=<<reverse).(`take`"123456789").length`` works for [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYzLCoMwFET3/YohdKFwlcR3QL@kFQw2PjA@UNvPb6rbOouzGM5Mp7ZBG2Ob4mkdh9wiz1f90eumXd@pdjXoiokgjOIkzSRzfaOndu/sqPoJBV7zDUeWtZ923NHgwRQjMH2iPzGfeLPy3/MEIQgIYUiIIkIcE5KEkKaELCNIeZlwgriUQkp5PHHOS/utG6PazXr1svwA).

Comment: `((,)<*>reverse).map fst.zip['1'..]`

Comment: That's a fairly different approach, you can go ahead and post that.

Comment: Nah, not that different, feel free to edit it in your post.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 52 bytes

```python
x=0
for _ in input():x=x*10+x%10+1
print x,`x`[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRLCoAgFAXQeatwEvS5QppZCa4kJEdRExMxeK3egsOJbz7vIEshO1THndjOrvCLT25aQ5Y6MfRU/4kqpitkRvDkN2O4cKVsXEBKjCOUwjRBa8wzlgXr6j4)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
Êõ ¬pÔò¶
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=yvUgrHDU8rY=&input=WzAsMSwyLDNd)

---

### Explanation

```
Ê            :Length
 õ           :Range [1,Ê]
   ¬         :Join
    p        :Concatenate
     Ô       : Reverse
      ò      :Partition
       ¶     : Between equal characters
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please have the decency to leave a comment.

Comment: Whoever did it downvoted every single answer, so they don't have a reason except being a jerk..

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/Code-page)

```
JṚƬḌ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r4c5Zx9Y83NHz////6GqlRCUrw1qdaqUkJSsjEJ2sZGVcGwsA)**

#### How?

```
JṚƬḌ - Link: list L    e.g. ['ant','bee','cat','dog','elk','frog']
J    - range of length      [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  Ƭ  - 'till (collect up until results are no longer unique):
 Ṛ   -   reverse                         1:[6,5,4,3,2,1] , 2:[1,2,3,4,5,6]=1st
     -                  ->  [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[6,5,4,3,2,1]]
   Ḍ - from base ten        [123456,654321]
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted all the answers: poor show.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
⟦⭆θ⊕κ⮌⭆θ⊕κ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCM6uARIp/smFmgU6ih45iUXpeam5pWkpmhka2rqKASllqUWFadq4FOlGatp/f9/dLRSopKOUioQZwJxPhCXKsXG/tctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ    θ    Input array
 ⭆    ⭆     Map over elements and join
    κ    κ  Current index (0-indexed)
   ⊕    ⊕   Increment
     ⮌      Reverse
⟦           Collect into an array
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes

```powershell
-join(1..($x=$args.count));-join($x..1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPw1BPT0OlwlYlsSi9WC85vzSvRFPTGiKlUqGnZ6j5//9/k//G/40A)

Takes input via splatting, which on the command-line prompt looks like, e.g., `$a=(4,3,2); .\array-to-indices.ps1 @a`, and on TIO manifests as separate arguments for each entry.

We take the `.count` of the input `$args`, store that into `$x`. Then construct a range `..` from `1` up to `$x` and `-join` it into a string. Finally we `-join` the range the other direction. Those two strings are left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 53 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$l#n=take(size l)['1'..]
=[n,reverse n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxCsIwEADQvV9x0EIV0mLcOmSrg@AgdCwdjvQqweQiSSyo@OtGwfENT1tCzs7Pd0vg0HA27uZDgiHNB16LypasEl5pE82TwG7HWtZtOxVqZBFopRAJeMpDwl9SUMGrlAK6TkAj9wJ27/zRi8VLzM3xlPsHozP6j7PFtPjgvg)

Answer (score 0):

## Scala (60 bytes)

```
def%(s:Seq[Any])={val a=(1 to s.size)mkString;(a,a.reverse)}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VYxPC4JAEEfvfYplQdiFUVCzsjDoA3TqGB1GncKy1dxN@kOf3cZTdHj8YHjzbIE1Dk1@psKJLVZG0MORKa3YtK14DyUdPWWXO7rtN@Z50Nm7x1pgpkLhGmEDW71IXy8711XmtFIIGHTUU2dJf4aWj642ylP8ryRKkMRUTMPcpdZ68pO22I6Svw5ByJw34i14Yx24hhN/9pj0Q4giiGOYTiFJYDaD@RwWC0jTsfwZvg)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 15 bytes

```
4(,:|.)@u:48+#\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/000dKxq9DQdSq1MLLSVY/5rcqUmZ@QrpCkYGioYGSkYGyuYmCiYmsJEjYyBPBNjBUM4A0qDKDMzUxOgiv8A)

#### How it works

```
4(,:|.)@u:48+#\
             #\  Generate 1-based indices of given array
          48+    Convert digits to ASCII value
4      @u:       Convert to string
 (,:|.)          Append its reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 58 bytes

```
_=>[_.map((_,i)=>t.unshift(++i),t=[]),t].map(_=>+_.join``)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcpLDoMgEIDhfY/BCuJowDcmeBFj0FptMRZM1W6MZ6e0y8bFP5PMfGP7bpfupebV1@bW20FYKcpKBs92xliCIqJcg00vDzWs2PMUgVVUtZv1jzjsyWA0SjcNsZ3Ri5n6YDJ3POAKtQhQ71Iu49pQTcjlT@2OFeyAHV1REX53h4roOJE@gzCEKII4hiSBNIUsgzwHzk8wBXZyZZxzCCml7mc/)

Pass current index of array plus `1` to `.unshift()` to fill first array with a second array's `.length`, `.join()` each resulting array without any characters separating elements and convert to integer. Returns an array of two integers.